# SharePoint chat icon embed iframe issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, sharepoint

Trying to embed a chatbot in SharePoint online. We're doing that with an iframe through True Editor Web Part http://prntscr.com/m3br5p

The issue is that even when the bot is folded like in this preview, clicking buttons behind its unfolded are (or scrolling) are not possible
folded: http://prntscr.com/m3brdk
unfolded: http://prntscr.com/m3brxu

We're also experiencing similar issues when trying to lightbox/popup certain things that we want to load. I wish we could have a layer on top of sharepoint where we could just do anything we want (being externally, no need to integrate) while keeping everything behind it in tact.

How should we deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at maybe using a Directline / React application customiser at all?

I found this useful after some re-jigging around and a better solution than using the iframe approach.

https://github.com/MickH3/directline-bot-extension